# selective export of data from excel to text file using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

The Objective is to copy the specific rows from a worksheet to a text file.

Specific rows say (B6:D6 , B7:D7 and B14:D14, B21:D21).

[image: Worksheet Image]

Comment: This isn't a specific, answerable question. There are multiple 'correct' ways to do this and such broad questions cause our voting system to jam up because there is no single 'best' answer.

Answer (score 1):

After few hours of effort this is the solution which might prove useful for many. The key is to use named range of the rows you require to copy.

> ```
> Private Sub btnExport_Click()
>
> Dim rng As Range
> Dim Sourceworksheet As Worksheet
> Dim DestFile As String
> Dim cel As Range
>
> 'Destination Path to place the text file.
>
> Application.DefaultFilePath = "\\path\"
>
> DestFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\Test.txt"
>
> Open DestFile For Output As #1
>
> Set Sourceworksheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
> ' select the data or rows you need to copy and make it named range.
> Set rng = ShAuReport.Range("DataAuReport")
>
>
>  For Each cel In rng.Cells
>
>  Write #1, cel.Address & "|" & cel.Value2      
>
>  Next cel
>
> Close #1
>
> MsgBox "txt file exported"
>
>
> End Sub
> ```

Regards,

Mani

Answer (score 0):

First add reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" to use "FileSystemObject"(Tools -> References -> check the box for "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" and click ok)

```
Sub WriteToTextFile()
  Dim fs As New FileSystemObject
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  Set txtfile = fs.CreateTextFile(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test.txt")
  Set rng = Union(ws.Range("B6:D6"), ws.Range("B7:D7"), ws.Range("B14:D14"), ws.Range("B21:D21"))
  For Each r In rng.Areas
      For Each cel In r
         txtfile.Write (cel.Value & " ")
      Next
      txtfile.Write (vbNewLine)
  Next
End Sub
```

See linnk:
'https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198716.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub WriteToTextFile3()
'THIS VARIATION SEST RANGE BY COLUMN
  Dim fs As New FileSystemObject
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  Set txtfile = fs.CreateTextFile(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TestAAA.txt")
  Set rng = Sheet1.Range("B2:B21")
  For Each r In rng.Cells
      For Each cel In r
         txtfile.Write (cel.Value & " ")
         txtfile.Write (cel.Offset(0, 1).Value & " ")
         txtfile.Write (cel.Offset(0, 2).Value & " ") 'MORE COLUMNS? ADD OFFSET
         Next cel
      txtfile.Write (vbNewLine)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Bill. Consider adding some context to your code-only answer. As it stands, I'm not sure how useful this answer is to others.